# Is there a Nagios plugin that enables you to specify the referrer URL when checking a URL?

Tags: nagios

I want to monitor site A that only accepts requests for a certain URL if the requests originate from site B. I know [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) has an option of downloading content protected by referrer like so

```
wget --referer=http://first_page http://second_page
```

Is there any [Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) plugin that would make this possible, or is [check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) capable of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the check_http man page:

-k, --header=STRING
     Any other tags to be sent in http header. Use multiple times for additional headers

http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http

Comment: thanks a bunch, I guess RTFM would have been the correct answer to my question.